# Resolving varying $ω$ in Kepler's Law's Proof

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, angular-velocity, celestial-mechanics

I'm having trouble understanding where $d^2r/dt^2$ comes from and what it stands for. What force is this? I'm not able to find any FBD's on google that mention any other force besides gravitational and centripetal force.

Also, why does $ω$ vary? Even if it is in an ellipse, and $ω$ is not constant, wouldn't $dr/dt$ also not be constant since the radius changes?

Here is the partial proof:

Kepler’s First Law
Note: I’m including the calculus derivation of the elliptic orbit, not to be found in the textbooks, just so you can see that it’s calculus, not magic, that gives this result.  This is an optional section, and will not appear on any exams.

We now back up to Kepler’s First Law: proof that the orbit is in fact an ellipse if the gravitational force is inverse square.  As usual, we begin with Newton’s Second Law: F = ma, in vector form. The force is $GMm/r^2$ in a radial inward direction. But what is the acceleration? Is it just $d^2r/dt^2$?  Well, no, because if the planet’s moving in a circular orbit it’s still accelerating inwards at $rw^2$ (same as v2/r) even though r is not changing at all. The total acceleration is the sum, so ma = F becomes:

$d^2r/dt^2-rw^2=-GM/r^2$

This isn’t ready to integrate yet, because w varies too. But since the angular momentum L is constant, $L = mr^2w$, we can get rid of w in the equation to give:

$d^2r/dt^2=-GM/r^2+r(L/mr^2)^2$

$=-GM/r^2+L^2/mr^3$

Here is the link to the website I found the proof on in case the screenshot isn't clear: http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/KeplersLaws.htm

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE.  Please, do not post text as a picture. Type the question instead.  There are many reasons, including making it trackable for the search engine and helping users who cannot read it (load failure, bad calligraphy, or anything else). In sum: avoid text on images, please.  Also, Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside, like this `$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$` . See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: *I'm having trouble understanding where $d^2r/dt^2$ comes from and what it stands for.* It’s the standard notation for the second [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of $r(t)$ in calculus. You’ll have to learn calculus before you can learn physics that uses calculus.

Answer (score 1):

What you are posting is just NEwton's second law.

The sum of forces must equal the product mass times acceleration.

The only force is the gravitational one, so "force of gravity = mass times acceleration"

$$-\dfrac{GMm}{r^2} = ma $$

Evidently, the mass of the planet cancels out, so you get

$$-\frac{GM}{r^2}=a$$

The only thing that is been doing here is that acceleration is a vector. Assuming it is a 2D movement (and it is, due to conservation of angular momentum), any vector can be split up in two components. Normally, we split accelration in $a_x$ and $a_y$. However, when dealing with orbits, it is more useful to use local coordinates: a tangential axis and a normal axis.

Both tangential and normal axis vary with time, since they move and rotate with the planet itself, but the key thing is that they are always orthogonal, so, Pithagoras still holds:

$$a^2 = a_t^2 +a_n^2$$

Then, recall that

$a_t=\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$, while $a_n=-\omega^2 r$. Of course, $d^2r/dt^2$ stands for the second derivative of the radius' modulus repect to time, I guess you're familiarized with that.

So that's where your equiation comes from. What I don't see is why there is a missing square root, I think. In fact, we normally work with energy equations, rather than forces

If you use the energy equation...

$$E_c+E_p=E$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 - \dfrac{GMm}{r}=E $$

$$\frac{1}{2}m \left[\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2+(\omega r)^2\right]- \dfrac{GMm}{r}=E $$

$$\frac{1}{2}m \left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2+ \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 r^2 - \dfrac{GMm}{r}=E $$

Finally, you also ask why $\omega$ varies. This is easily derived from conservation of angular momentum. Anyways, you couldn't have assumed it is constant, you should always consider it a variable, just in case, unless there is something that prevents it from varying. However, in this case it is clear: it does vary due to conservation of $L$.

Comment: If omega varies, would radius vary as well? If so, why am I able to integrate $dr/dt$ but not $dθ/dt$?

Comment: Of course. You know, due to conservation of angular momentum, that $r$ and $\omega$ are inversely proportional, as long as the mass doesn't vary, so yes, both $r$ and $\omega$ do vary, but they are related to each other. You have to integrate in one variable only. You could choose either of them, but $r$ is far easier. That's why you rewite $\omega$ in terms of $r$. $\omega=\frac{L}{mr^2}$. Doing this, you only have 1 variable so you can perform the integral

Comment: thank you. another stupid question, whats the difference between $d^2r/dt^2$ and $d^2θ/dt^2$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The symbol $\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\right)$ must be regarded "as a block". It means "second derivative of the variable with respect to time. $d/dt$ is first derivative, $d^2/dt^2$ is the second derivative. Is your question about the difference between $r$ and $\theta$? Because they are obviously different variables. Their derivatives will also be different...

Comment: yeah. is dr the changing of the radius while dtheta is the changing of the angle?

Comment: Kind of, yes. $dr$ alone is an infinitesimal change of $r$, that is, an infinitely small $\Delta r$. However, you should not regard $dr/dt$ as a quotient of two differentials. Rather, you should regard $d/dt$ as a block, which means "take the derivative of what comes afterwards. So $dr/dt$ is the infinitesimally small version of $\Delta r/ \Delta t$? To some extent, but you should see that as the derivative of $r$.